# How to use ternary operator in jquery within ajax call?

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu, ternary-operator

I am using core PHP, jQuery and MySql. I have 2 dependent dropdowns in my code. The first dropdown of `company list` is coming from the database directly with a query on the same page.

For the second dropdown of `employee list` of particular `company`, I am using ajax to get data from database.

```
var lastSelectedEmpId = $('#hiddeniid').val();
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  dataType: 'json',
  url:"getdata.php?id="+emp_id,
  success:function (response){
    $(".bodytable").empty();
    $.each(response, function( index, value ) {
      $(".class").append("<option value="'+value.id+','+value.emp_type+'">" + value.emp_name + </option>'");
    });
  },
});
```

As you can see above code in value `"'+value.id+','+value.emp_type+'"`

On `_GET['curent_id']` I am getting selected users all data.

My add and update code is on same page. So I have only single ajax call for `employee_list.`

As you see above code on `_GET['curent_id']`, I am getting all data with `id_emptype` of employee.

I want this `id_emptype`to use in ajax call as selected option. For this, I want to use a ternary operator inside jQuery, but it's not working
for me.

I have one hidden field with my current `id_emptype`. in variable `lastSelectedEmpId`.

Now I'm doing something like below code to get `current id_emptype` as selected value onload page, but its not working:

```
$(".class").append<option value="' +value.id+','+value.emp_type+ '"' +
  (+value.id+','+value.emp_type+ === lastSelectedEmpId ? 'selected="selected"' : '') +
  '>' + value.emp_name + '</option>;
```

Comment: `.append()` needs some parenthesis!

Comment: this is typo @LouysPatriceBessette.  that is not a problem i guess. i correct it in my code.

Comment: Well, edit that last code chunk and make sure there is no other typos. Then, one may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When concatenating some JS logic with a string, you have to wrap it with parenthesis.

And be careful where you put the `+` signs and the parenthesis. You just can't have them at the wrong place or missing.

Try the `.append()` below, where I filled the variables with stuff to have the demo working:

```js
var lastSelectedEmpId = "1,type";

var value={
  id:1,
  emp_type:"type",
  emp_name:"John Doh"
}

$(".class").append('<option value="' +value.id+','+value.emp_type+ '"' + 
                   ((value.id+','+value.emp_type === lastSelectedEmpId) ? 'selected="selected"' : '') +
                   '>' + value.emp_name + '</option>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="class">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

===
And `'selected="selected"'` could simply be `'selected'`. That attribute is a true/false anyway. But browsers interpret it to be true simply if present.

You can even try `'selected="bullshit"'` and it will work... ;)